# Core Plot graph height not filling up hosting view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, graph, core-plot

The height of my Core Plot graph is significantly shorter than the height of its graph hosting view (`CPTGraphHostingView`, created from xib).  The width seems to be fine.

I have the same code for a "full screen" graph (the hosting view is the same size as the parent `UIView`), and its height and width are both fine.  Only the hosting view that fills up roughly half of the screen has this problem.

I can still achieve the desired graph height by stretching the hosting view *past* where it should be, but I'd like to find out why this is occurring and fix it.  What properties should I try to adjust?

(It's not `paddingTop` or `paddingBottom`.  I've tried those.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph always fills the hosting view. Either the hosting view isn't being sized like you intended or there is extra padding on the graph and/or plot area frame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Eric.  What properties should I check for extra padding?  I'm a bit confused because I have another graph that's working fine.  I can't seem to find what's causing the issue.

Comment: The issue was resolved when I deleted the hosting view from the xib and created a new one with the same dimensions.  No changes to code were made, so it must have been caused by accidentally changing a property in the xib on my part.